# Joystick Android Client Control Arduino

Tags: java, android, arduino, tcpclient

In my Android Client App I'm trying to send virtual joystick coordinates over socket from client(Android) to a server(Arduino).I'm Tray Codding a thread 't' in main activity containing a socket 's', to send x,y Coordinate to  arduino Server.
the JoystickView Class give me 'x' and 'y' when I move the joystick.
this will be done after user Click  Connect button,
'x' is from 0 to 255, also 'y' but to be able to know witch value is 'x' and witch is 'y' in arduino side, I added 255 to y so y will be from 255 to 510.

virtual joy stick provide me with 'x','y' Coordinate Stored in public variables 'xxx' and 'yyy'.
Linked a Connect Button with thread 't, Created I socket 's' to send 'x','y' to server.

**my Question: can my Code works with the Arduino and Can I get x,y in Arduino Side ?, also I couldn't put thread 't' in "public void onClick(View v)" function. its the second problem :( **

```
package com.ravensoft.daniel.joysticktest;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
JoystickView.JoystickListener{
TextView x;
TextView y;

 public float xxx=0;//bublic var will Contain x value from virtual 
 joystick
 public float yyy=0;//bublic var  will Contain x value from virtual 
 joystick
    EditText txt_IP;//arduino ip
    EditText txt_PORT;//arduino port
    private volatile Socket socket = null;
    private boolean connectionOk = false;
    private Button buttonDisconnect; //button for disconnect connection 
    private Button buttonConnect;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        JoystickView joystick = new JoystickView(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        buttonConnect = findViewById(R.id.buttonConnect);
        buttonDisconnect = findViewById(R.id.buttonDisconnect);
        JoystickView joystic =findViewById(R.id.joystick);
        txt_IP=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_IP);
        txt_PORT=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_PORT);


        buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        buttonDisconnect.setEnabled(false);
        buttonConnect.setEnabled(true);
    }
        Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 try {
                     Socket s = new Socket(txt_IP.getText().toString(),Integer.parseInt(txt_PORT.getText().toString() ));
                     s.connect(new InetSocketAddress(txt_IP.getText().toString(), Integer.parseInt(txt_PORT.getText().toString() )), 50);
                     if(s == null)System.out.println("SOCKET NULL");
                     DataOutputStream DataOut = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

                     String message=  Float.toString(xxx+256);
                     byte[] msgBuffer=message.getBytes();
                     String message2=  Float.toString(yyy);
                     byte[] msgBuffer2=message2.getBytes();

                    try {
                        DataOut.write(msgBuffer);

                        DataOut.write(msgBuffer2);
                    }catch (IOException e){

                    }
                      DataOut.flush();

                     s.close();


                 } catch (IOException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }

             }
         });




    @Override
    public void onJoystickMoved( float xPercent, float yPercent) {

        x = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.x_value);
        x.setText(Float.toString(xPercent));

        y = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.y);
        y.setText(Float.toString(-yPercent));

        xxx=xPercent;
        yyy=yPercent;
            Log.d("Right Joystick", "X percent: " + xPercent + " Y percent: " + yPercent);

    }}
```

Comment: What's the question? What kind of trouble are you facing with this code?

Comment: thank you for Replay. Can I Start thread ' t'  in  Connect button " public void onClick(View v) { }".
and close socket in Disconnect button.

Comment: thank you for Replay. Can I Start thread ' t'  in  Connect button " public void onClick(View v) { }".
and close socket in Disconnect button.